# How to filter points (LAT, LONG) on a map within a line boundary I created

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, line, boundaries

I am fairly new to QGIS and I have a data set of points that I have plotted with lat & long. The points cover a large area and I'm am trying to figure out if there is a way to only show the points within an artificial boundary that I have created as a layer with the line tool. Basically, I have all these points outside of the boundary that I have created that I want to delete, or at least no appear on the map.

[image]

Comment: Vector > Research tools > Select by Location

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert the line to a polygon using `Menu Vector > Geometry Tools > Lines to polygons`.
2. Run select by expression on the point layer with this expression: `overlay_disjoint ('polygons')` - replace `polygons` with the name of your polygon layer (output from step 1).
3. Delete selected points. To delete, first select `toggle editing` (pen icon or keybord shortcut `E`), then press the delete icon.

*Blue: initial point layer; dark red: initial line; light red: polygon created in step 1; yellow: points selected in step 2:*
[image]

Comment: Where do go to run the expression?

Comment: See screenshot I just posted

Comment: OK great, thanks. I think I got it to work and the points have changed to to different colors, but I cannot figure out how to delete the points on the outside of the boundary.

Comment: The button for "delete selected" is grayed out and not available to click

Comment: See edited answer for that. However, that is very very basic QGIS stuff, you should first make yourself confident with basic vector editing before going to more complex workflows. See e.g. https://youtu.be/kCnNWyl9qSE - especially at 10:50: https://youtu.be/kCnNWyl9qSE?t=650

Comment: I can't get toggle editing available for selection or delete. Thanks, I will watch the video.

Comment: Be sure you have the point layer selected. If still no success, according to the policy of this site, you should post another post as this is a different question.